# Error message "Unfortunately Smartface emulator stopped" is always shown on android device

Tags: android, smartface.io

After debugging a project, the application starts on android device but the error message "Unfortunately Smartface emulator stopped" has always been shown when I unlock the screen. I could not fix it.

Is there anyone else who faces this error message?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a known issue for Android emulator, and it is already fixed.

Next release of Smartface App Studio will be ready soon and you will be able to use it without facing this error.

Answer (score 0):

Open your AVD Manager and then open the configuration of your Emulator. In android studio, click on advanced options, there will be option called "VM heap"
try changing it to 32, if that doesn't work then try 64.

Comment: I could not understand why you advise to configure AVD Manager. I work with a real android device, so I get that error message on screen of the real device.

Comment: you haven't mentioned that you are testing your app on your own device, look in your question, also most of all people test their application on emulator of android studio or eclipse, and generally this error comes in emulator. that's the reason i gave you this answer.

Comment: Yes, it was my mistake, sorry, but although I work my own device, why this type of error is shown on the device?

Answer (score 0):

One way to fix this is to go to your phone Settings - > Developer options (depends on your device manufacturer) and check "Stay awake" (so the screen will never go to sleep while connected)

Hope this helps.